# Where can I find Apache Thrift 0.12.0 for Windows?

Tags: thrift

I need to find the thrift 0.12.0 exe for windows.

It has been deprecated so I can't get it from Apache anymore.

The backstory: We don't use thrift in a standard way. We just use it for generating classes and serialising objects in our Unity game client and server. When I tried a later version of thrift a couple years ago they had replaced C# with NetStd which doesn't work with Unity game, and added a bunch of http code to their memory buffer class.

Answer (score 1):

Since its open source you can build it yourself. Some version of Visual Studio will do, plus (e.g.) WinFlexBison to parse the syntax definition.

> replaced C# with NetStd

The netstd bindings still offer netstd2 as compilation target which is compatible with .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks for your tip regarding netstd2